# Can't Write to .obb directory for Expansion file

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I am having major issues with my ".obb" directory which I need for expansion files. I can create a directories under it, but I can not place a data file in the directory. For example, I try to copy main.1.com.abc.groovebasstrial to /obb/com.abc.groovebasstrial/. I get the following error when using Android File Transfer: "could not copy file "main.1.com.abc.groove".

When using adb:

I cannot see the directories that I created.

I have also tried deleting the directory. I get the following error:"Cannot delete file or folder called obb". It said file may be busy. 
However, I can create other directories and move the file to them. For example, I created a folder call "obt" and added the data file to it with no problem. I also stopped all apps that may have been accessing the directory. I have search online, but no one seem to have this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @Alamri  I already have this in my android manifest file.

Comment: could you please post some the code?

Comment: @Alamri I posted my manifest. I am trying to add the file to the directory manually.

Comment: i meant the code of (copy, delete) and some LogCat would be helpful.

Comment: @Alamri Thanks for your help. I was able to use this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected my problem by having my code copy/write the file to the directories that I needed. I was not able to do it manually using Android File Transfer. The example that helped me correct my problem was: [How to copy files from 'assets' folder to sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard)